# jquery form serialize using load method

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to submit POST data for a form using the jQuery LOAD function, sending the form's serialized data.

so, by way of example, how do i do this:

```
$('someElement').click(function(){
    var formData = $('formHere').serialize();
    $('anotherElement').load('somePage', formData);
)};
```

as it stands, this doesn't work - if won't POST the data, but rather sends a GET request. I don't want to start using the $.post method (because i just don't want to!), am i doing something wrong here?

SOLUTION: use serialiazeArray instead - as in

```
var formData = $('formHere').serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [jQuery docs for `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#request-method) it seems as if the POST method is used if the data (in this case `formData` is an object. Otherwise it uses GET. However, the [docs for `.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) indicate that it returns a string. Hence always the GET.

Comment: No idea, but it looks like someone has it covered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery

Answer (score 8):

**Easy**: use `serializeArray()` rather than `serialize()`.

`serialize()` returns a string, whereas `serializeArray()` returns an object. `load()` sends a POST if the data is an object. If data is a string, `load()` sends a GET.

Answer (score 0):

if you must have a post, use `$.post` otherwise you would need to use $.ajaxSettings to configure global ajax. `$.load`, `$.get()` , `$.getJSON()` &  `$.post` are convenience wrappers of `$.ajax` with some of the options already taken care of to minimize code required.

```
 $('someElement').click(function(){
    var formData = $('formHere').serialize();
    $.post('somePage', formData, function(data){
        $(selector).html(data);                                
    });
});
```

API has examples of using `$(form).serialize()` with `$.post`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/